# What's the difference between died and has died?

Tags: word-usage

1. My rabbit died.
2. My rabbit has died.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: "My rabbit died" is a simple story about the past, and should include a finished past time. "My rabbit has died" is an indirect way of saying "my rabbit is dead".

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct.

In BE, you use the present perfect (has died) for recent actions, whereas you use the past simple (died) for something that happened in the past. Look at the following sentences:

My rabbit died yesterday/last week.

My rabbit has just died/has died today.

But in AE, you can use either the past simple or the present perfect for recent actions. for example, my rabbit just died/has just died.

Comment: It isn't so much the recency (closeness to present) that determines the choice of tense, but the bearing or effect the event is perceived to have upon the present, that it is "touching" the present in some way. *My rabbit died a minute ago.*  "A minute ago" is in the past. Perfectly grammatical. *My rabbit has died a second ago.* The perfect here is ungrammatical. Now consider: Little Johnny comes home from summer camp, hoping to see his pet rabbit. Dad says: *Johnny, I'm sorry to say, your rabbit has died. -- When did he die, Dad?  Your rabbit died three weeks ago, Johnny*.

Comment: Tromano, I know what you have said.  I tried to make my reply as simple and general as possible;. BTW, thanks for you comments.